# Bootstrap : Caroussel takes full space of col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a difficult for that my carousel takes all height of my col :

The link Fiddle : www.jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16241/

So my carousel is in my "col-md-9". The height of col-md-9 is more higher than the height of the carousel...

So I want my carousel takes all place of my col-md-9 please

Comment: Would be easier if you made it to a fiddle.

.myCarousel {
    max-width:100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Allright, i fixed it for you. 
Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16237/).

Just gave the class my-carousel a `width of 100%;`

Comment: No, I think I misspoke.. I edith the post with a Fiddle !

Comment: Checked it out... The problem you are having is that you don't specify a height for the green box. Once you give that div (#connexion) a height i will be able to solve this for you :)

Comment: I want the red box has the same height than the green box.. The height of green box is variable